# I may be met a rendering problem when I used the Canvas of QML to draw a line

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I encapsulate a control with canvas. When it get a coordinate array, it can draw the trajectory the array discribed.But during development process，I met a problem and I will simplify the problem in this question.
First ,let us read the code following.

```
 Canvas {
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    width: 500
    height: 500

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        border.width: 1
        color: "transparent"
    }

    onPaint: {
        var ctx = getContext('2d')
        ctx.lineWidth = 2
        ctx.strokeStyle = "yellow"

        ctx.beginPath()

        ctx.moveTo(100, 100)
        ctx.lineTo(300, 100)

        ctx.moveTo(100, 150)
        ctx.lineTo(300, 150)
        ctx.lineTo(100, 150)
        ctx.lineTo(300, 150)

        ctx.closePath()
        ctx.stroke()
    }
}
```

The output is:
[image]

When I draw along with a line or an arc back and forth, the both ends of the line will automatically draw an extra section.
But the data is large,I can avoid this phenomenon.
So do you konw the solution？Could some one teach me?It is important for me,thanks a lot!

Comment: If I get your question correctly, you want to avoid "redrawing" of segments that already exist. It can be done, but only as long as you're sure that each subpath draws in the same context (different arcs for the same bounding rect of the ellipse, points along the same line, etc.). If that's the case, then create a function that gets each subpath and "reduce" the final result to the full extent of the line or arc. But if you are not sure about that, there's very little you can do, and trying to work around it may be even worse than having the rendered drawing again the same paths.

Answer (score 1):

This extra drawing is caused by the [`lineJoin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineJoin) property, which by default is set to `miter`.
To solve this issue, you can change `ctx.lineJoin` to either `bevel` or `round`.

You can also adjust the [`miterLimit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/miterLimit) property to limit the the miter ratio.

```js
ctx.strokeStyle = 'yellow';
ctx.lineJoin = 'bevel'; // or 'round'
// ctx.miterLimit = 1;
```

Comment: This is the correct answere!

Comment: !!!!!!!!!Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can close your path before a call to `moveTo()`. This is somehow just a workaround, I guess:

```
Canvas {
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    width: 500
    height: 500

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        border.width: 1
        color: "transparent"
    }

    onPaint: {
        var ctx = getContext('2d')
        ctx.lineWidth = 2
        ctx.strokeStyle = "yellow"

        ctx.beginPath()

        ctx.moveTo(100, 100)
        ctx.lineTo(300, 100)

        // close path 
        ctx.closePath()
        ctx.stroke()

        // start new path
        ctx.beginPath()

        ctx.strokeStyle = "green"

        ctx.moveTo(100, 150)
        ctx.lineTo(300, 150)
        ctx.lineTo(100, 150)
        ctx.lineTo(300, 150)

        ctx.closePath()
        ctx.stroke()
    }
}
```

Another workaround is to set the lineWidth below 0.9. This is really strange. Guess, this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Ｉ got an idea,although it is not perfect way but it can meet my needs.Just call the moveTo() the same point  after lineTo() .

```
Canvas {
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    width: 500
    height: 500

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        border.width: 1
        color: "transparent"
    }

    onPaint: {
        var ctx = getContext('2d')
        ctx.lineWidth = 5
        ctx.strokeStyle = "yellow"

        if (root.coordList.length > 0) {
            var startPoint = root.coordList[0]
            var startX = startPoint[0]
            var startY = startPoint[1]
            ctx.moveTo(startX, startY)
            for (var i = 1; i < root.coordList.length; i++) {
                var point = root.coordList[i]
                var x = point[0]
                var y = point[1]
                ctx.lineTo(x, y)
                ctx.moveTo(x, y)
            }
        }

        ctx.stroke()
    }
}
```

When called moveTo(),it means the last line has been over.So the rendering problem will not appear.

Comment: The coordList example->
property var coordList: [[100, 100], [150, 100], [170, 100], [200, 100], [170, 100], [150, 100], [100, 100]]

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `QtQuick.Shapes` instead of `Canvas`? Also, why not use `Repeater` instead of for-loop? In the following, you can use either an array or a `ListModel` as input:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    background: Rectangle { color: "black" }
    DrawLines {
        model: [
            {x1:100,y1:100,x2:300,y2:100,c:"yellow"},
            {x1:100,y1:150,x2:300,y2:150,c:"yellow"},
            {x1:100,y1:150,x2:300,y2:150,c:"yellow"},
        ]
    }
    DrawLines {
        y: 200
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement {x1:100;y1:100;x2:300;y2:100;c:"cyan"}
            ListElement {x1:100;y1:150;x2:300;y2:150;c:"cyan"}
            ListElement {x1:100;y1:150;x2:300;y2:150;c:"cyan"}
        }
    }
}

// DrawLines.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Shapes
Item {
    property alias model: repeater.model
    Repeater {
        id: repeater
        Shape {
            ShapePath {
                startX: x1 ?? modelData.x1
                startY: y1 ?? modelData.y1
                strokeColor: c ?? modelData.c
                PathLine {
                    x: x2 ?? modelData.x2
                    y: y2 ?? modelData.y2
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAEJnictVM9b4MwFNz5FRZzRICKxQwZkg6VUilJl1ZVB8d5SqwYTI2jYEX892JDPnCI1KG9Bd5xJ997frCsEFKhpVoeGN17rFcGU5ErKXjpLcgW0MlDDdaE7rdSHPINRiugiuRb3nxDVHAhMfLXvBH4qLbimSTHOcuh7MwGmdgAx+jzQhicqghHYTjS7aOK8ZOpYltR7GvgXBz9evTQlfRcyZ+6vuzb45Y0RnEYuh3OWalezeuN0sDwzxwyyNU5S9r2nbZZ0rbvtMlCNcn9+lf2pGdP/sFed2OoPW88vg4i+M64szkPF8nh33akgNJ7UZB1QyqkKEAqjQhnpDyPUkIBRIEMbG2Fq466GS7bXJUX0h7h3IDlFkTtHN6gVESqd4yqCE0m7fkzokhQRcPSD4y0I9VDUin2MG3/EdqX0zu1iWZGOxDPoGrSxU66eFDZLKZ2lPpe2V+Qgfv+ARAeFJQ=)